# Swapping words Hello,Python to Python,Hello index of range index

Tags: list, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a code in python to swap Hello Python as Python Hello.
While executing I'm getting list index out of range Error.could you tell me what is the mistake I did.

```
string="Hello,Python"
a=[]
b=[]
c=[]
cc=0
for i in range(0,len(string)):
    a.append(string[i])
print(a)
for j in range(0,len(a)):
    b[j]=a[j]
    if(a[j]==' '):
        break
    for k in range(j,len(a)):
        c[cc]=k[j]
        cc=+1
print(c+b)
```

Comment: Your code snippet has quite a few bugs and does not handle the space correctly. After fixing the bugs, it would give `PythonHello `. A more pythonic solution would be `' '.join(string.split(' ')[::-1])`

Comment: Thanks @jaco I got answer ','.join(string.split(',')[::-1]) it will give Python,Hello.

Answer (score 0):

`len(string)` returns nubmer of characters in a string including spaces etc. Character indexes in a string are numbered from 0 to `len(string)-1`. In your loop you are trying to get access to character with index which doesn't exist. Try replacing `len(string)` with `len(string)-1`. I hope it will help and you understand mistake

Answer (score 0):

In line 10,
`b` is initialized as an empty list, but you've attempting to write to an index of it. But it doesn't exist.

You can try to append to it instead -

```
for j in range(0,len(a)):
    b.append(a[j])
```

I'm assuming you meant `j` and not `i` in this step...

Here's an updated code - http://ideone.com/uVRIG1